# Why do my UITabBar button appears distorted and button font changes?

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBar application that also involves a UINavController and then a UITableView so:

UITabBarView -> UINavController -> UITableView -> UIController

When I go into UIController view I hide the tabar show I can maximize the view. When I go back to the my UITableView then the tabbar shows for 1 second offset upwards before it re-renders into the correct position but with the fonts different. See below the photos to assist in understanding the problem:

[Normal View of the TabBar shown below the UITableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNXkE.png)

[UIControlView with the TabBar hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB2Zl.png)

[Re-rendered TabBar under the UITableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcTv5.png)

Unfortunately I can't grab the animation where it shows the TabBar icons out of the UITabBar area.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the code how you hide / unhide the tabbar?

Comment: Hi @Mocha - to hide the TabBar I just check on the StoryBoard section of the UIViewController where it says "Hide the Bottom Bar when View is Pushed". I am not doing anything to unhide the tabbar again.

Comment: Hm. I am not as familiar with xibs. Perhaps you can do this programatically by setting self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = true  for the UIController and self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = false for the UINavController in viewWillAppear

Comment: Thanks for the assistance @Mocha I added the self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = false for the UINavController in viewWillAppear and then the I set it to "true" in the viewWillDissappear. It now works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the UITabBar using storyboard and when you go back to UITabBar will show.

First go the storyboard and select the view that you want to hide the TabBar when the view show, and enable the Hide Boutton bar on push

and to transition to the view that you want to hide theTabBar use this code:

```
 let SecondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourview") as! yourview
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController, animated: true)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using xib, you can do this programmatically by setting the tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = false/true in your viewWillAppear methods

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true // or false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assistance of @Mocha, I added the self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = false for the UINavController in viewWillAppear and then the I set it to "true" in the viewWillDissappear.

Comment: Of course! I was surprised to see you did not post the answer! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue under Xcode 10.1 and Simulator 12.1:

- weird animation on coming back from a hidden tab bar (using 'Hides Bottom Bar on Push'); TabBar items are outside the TabBar and offset to the left and above the TabBar, then come into place
- distorted display of TabBarItems afterwards

To me it looks that it is related to the simulator rendering as it works fine when testing on device.

If someone else is having this issue, I would suggest to first quickly try testing on a real device (before investing a lot of time).